# Can I act on and then forward the results of a AngularJS $http call without using $q?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have functions like the getData function below.

I understand that $http returns a promise. In my current set up I am using $q so that I can do some processing of the results and then return another promise:

```
var getData = function (controller) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api/' + controller + '/GetData')
        .success(function (data) {
            var dataPlus = [{ id: 0, name: '*' }].concat(data);
            defer.resolve({
                data: data,
                dataPlus: dataPlus
            });
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            defer.reject({
                data: error
            });
        });
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Is there any way that I can do this without needing to use the AngularJS $q (or any other $q implementation) or is the code above the only way to do this? Note that I am not looking for a solution where I pass in an onSuccess and an onError to the getData as parameters.

Thanks

Comment: `$http.get` itself returns a promise. You could return that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say `$http.get` already returns a promise. One of the best things about promises is that they compose nicely. Adding more `success`, `then`, or `done` simply runs them sequentially.

```
var getData = function (controller) {
    return $http.get('/api/' + controller + '/GetData')
        .success(function (data) {
            var dataPlus = [{ id: 0, name: '*' }].concat(data);
            return {
                data: data,
                dataPlus: dataPlus
            };
        })
        .error(function (error) {
            return {
                data: error
            };
        });
}
```

This means that using `getData(controller).then(function (obj) { console.log(obj) });`, will print the object returned by your success handler.

If you want you can keep composing it, adding more functionality. Lets say you want to always log results and errors.

```
var loggingGetData = getData(controller).then(function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
}, function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return err;
});
```

You can then use your logging `getData` like so:

```
loggingGetData(controller).then(function (obj) {
    var data = obj.data;
    var dataPlus = obj.dataPlus;
    // do stuff with the results from the http request
});
```

If the `$http` request resolves, the result will first go through your initial success handler, and then through the logging one, finally ending up in the final function here.

If it does not resolve, it will go through the initial error handler to the error handler defined by `loggingGetData` and print to console. You could keep adding promises this way and build really advanced stuff.

Comment: Does `.error` return the original promise? Do you not need to return the result from `.get` instead?

Comment: @RGraham both `.error` and `.success` return the same chain of promises.

Comment: The defer.reject() in your .error callback is undefined. Did you mean to remove or change it?

Comment: Thanks Erik, couldn't find anything in the docs about what those http-specific methods returned

Comment: @ErikKronberg - Thanks for your answer. To make it really clear could you possibly update your answer to show also the case where there was some error and done pre-processing before the return. To make it more clear I just made a small change to the question. I'm very interested to see the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

Using an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#interceptors) which provides the `response` method. However I don't like it, as it moves the code handling the response to another place, making it harder to understand and debug the code.

Using $q would be the best in that case IMO.

Another (better ?) option is locally augmented `transformResponse` [transformer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#transforming-requests-and-responses) for the `$http.get()` call, and just return the $http promise.